# JMeter - The JVM should have exited but did not

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a script which does the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Script executes fine in GUI mode:

```
jmeter -q C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/eml_base.properties -t Service_Names.jmx
```

When executed in Non-GUI mode i.e.

```
jmeter -q C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/eml_base.properties -n -t Service_Names.jmx
```

We receive the below message:

[image]

Have added an entry in the log4j2.xml file. Restarted JMeter.

[image]

Executed the script again in Non-GUI mode. Still see the same message. Didn't find anything suspicious in the log file.

[image]

Not sure where is the issue. Please help.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

> Script executes fine in GUI mode:
>
> ```
> jmeter -q C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/eml_base.properties -t Service_Names.jmx
> ```

it doesn't mean that the "script executes fine", it means that you're just opening `Service_Names.jmx` test plan in JMeter GUI, the script is being "executed" when you click this button:

[image]

Or press `CTRL+R`

Your test cannot be finished successfully (in fact there are no successful Sample Results) because [SSH Command sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) is still waiting for the response from the SSH server.

I don't know what `eml status` command does and how does the output look like,try running it via new instance of [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (or whatever is your [shell](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0010.php)) interpreter as:

```
/bin/bash -c "eml status"
```

If the command is interactive, i.e. the output never ends until you press the button, you will need to reconsider your approach.

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)